# react-native Build Failed - > Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: react-native

- I have been building the react-native with no issue until i decided to npm install lottie-react-native
- after following the instructions on a site to use this dependency i then attempted to rebuild my react-native app.
- I did attempt to roll back all changes that git found added or modified. Even after that it still fails to build.
- Now when I execute "native-react run-android" the build fails with the following below:

warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 883 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

10 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 9 up-to-date
C:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
  >       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
  >       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
at runOnAllDevices (c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:169:41)
at then.result (c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums>react-native run-android
warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 883 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

10 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 9 up-to-date
C:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
  >       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
  >       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
at runOnAllDevices (c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:169:41)
at then.result (c:\Temp\MobileDevelopment\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the new androidx and old v4/v7 support libraries (or better your dependencies are). Use jetifier to convert the libraries as explained here: https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/issues/443#issuecomment-508240279

If you roleback I recommend to clean the gradle output will `./gradlew.bat clean` This will remove any generated output and normally helps to get the project up and running again

Comment: What is it that makes you determine that is the issue? Just trying to learn here.

- I ran ./gradlew.bat clean it said it build successfully.
- ran the jetifier next and installed successfully, and it look like it converted all dependencies.
- I then ran "react-native run-android" and the build still failed.

Comment: Have you followed the upgrade path from 0.59 to 0.60? As @kike-gamboa outlined you have to enable jetifier in the gradle properties, but you have to add some other things as well. See https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: i enabled jetifier like @kike-gamboa said. it compiled after that but when the app launched it was just a white screen and said "app keeps stopping". So this upgrade helper link you have provided is suppose to upgrade me? Im confused all i did was npm install lottie-react-native and now your saying have i followed the upgrade path? everything was working fine before lottie was installed, i never intended to upgrade? i just wanted to use that dependency in my project.

Answer (score 0):

just add these to lines at "gradle.properties"

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I did this and it actually did build but the android emulator just showed a white screen for the app. and it just says the app "keeps stopping"

Comment: Then you could try:

    sudo chmod -R 777 node-modules 
    sudo chmod -R 777 android